# Android : Getting manifest merge error when I gradle my project

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

and build.gradle file is

```
  android { compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bhatti.testapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled = true
        jackOptions {
            enabled true}
       ...}
    ....} compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }}

     dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':chat-sdk-ui')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use same SDK version for all the   `dependencies`

```
 android { compileSdkVersion 27
            defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.bhatti.testapplication"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            multiDexEnabled = true
            jackOptions {
                enabled true}
           ...}
        ....} compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }}

         dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        implementation project(':chat-sdk-ui')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: @ansarabbas it's simple update  `minSdkVersion 14` to  `minSdkVersion 15`

Comment: @ansarabbas i have updated the answer for ` minSdkVersion =15`

Comment: yes I have update but i am getting this error!

`Error:Execution failed for task ':chat-sdk-firebase-ui:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
 is also present at [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at manifestMerger6644887572933231228.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.`

Comment: @ansarabbas you have to download latest code from https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-android,there have already updated the code see https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-android/blob/master/gradle.properties

Comment: yes I have download the latest version. Also I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
```

to

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
```

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':chat-sdk-firebase-ui:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
 is also present at [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at manifestMerger5444918781287289278.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.